# Indy TIdHTTPServer.OnCommandGet - which port was connected to?

Tags: delphi, indy

I have a `TIdHTTPServer` that is reachable on multiple ports (due to migration) and I need to find out where the current data (in `OnCommandGet`) is coming from. Where can I retrieve the correct port number from?

Comment: From `AContext.Connection.Socket.BoundPort`, I guess. I wrote this using Indy online help (have no Delphi by hand; will get in few days back from holidays).

Comment: @TLama the `BoundPort` is used for clients, not servers. In this case, the correct property is `ABinding.Connection.Socket.Binding.Port`, or `AContext.Binding.Port` for short.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in `AContext.Binding.Port`.

Tested with the following in the CommandGet handler for a IdHTTPServer in Delphi 10.3.3:

```
AResponseInfo.ContentText := '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"> +
  '<head><title>A Test Response</title></head>' +
  '<body>Target port: ' + IntToStr(AContext.Binding.Port) +
  '</body></html>';
```